# Differences between clojure versions

Tags: clojure

I can't find any documentation about it. What are the differences? Are there only bug fixes? Is new version a drop in replacement of the older one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are release notes in the source tree.

https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md

Comment: great, thx! is there such file for all versions or i have to switch between branches?

Comment: You can view the historical versions as well, e.g., https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commits/master/changes.md -- it also used to be [a text file](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/commits/e5d3bfe66821084d1a3d651270d528931d690e69/changes.txt).

Answer (score 3):

There was a huge break-up with the past going from 1.2 to 1.3—not in the core, but in the *contrib* library. We had to rewrite all the code that depended on the old contrib, and it was big work. Release 1.4 introduced a breaking change regarding integer literals, which switched from `Integer` to `Long`. This broke a lot of Java interop code, but was trivial to fix. Release 1.5 is the cleanest increment, with no breaking changes at all (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

In general, it will be a combination of both bug fixes and new enhancements. You can also expect some performance improvements.

It is *usually* a drop-in replacement since the intention is to maintain backwards compatibility. There is the possibility that some breaking changes may occur in special cases, however I've updated several projects myself from the 1.4 release to 1.5 beta and there have been no problems.

As always when updating a major dependency, you should test with the new version thoroughly.